# Node Function Returning Empty Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following node function, it is returning an empty array. Not sure why its doing that. Could this be a async await issue? Would appreciate any help. Thank you

```
const folderPath = '/public/home.html'

function getCircuitAndFuse(folderPath){
  //List containing circuit name with its fuse
  let temporaryList = [];
  let finalCircuitAndFuseList = []

  fs.readFile(__dirname + folderPath, (error, data)=>{
    if(error){
      console.log(`Unable to read file: ${error}`)
    }else{

      var $ = cheerio.load(data)

      $('img').each(function(index, element){
        let getClassAtr = element.attribs.class
        temporaryList.push(getClassAtr.slice(0, getClassAtr.lastIndexOf(" ")))
      })

      finalCircuitAndFuseList = [...new Set(temporaryList)]
    }
  })
return finalCircuitAndFuseList;
}
let getInfo = getCircuitAndFuse(folderPath)

// Returning empty array
console.log(getInfo)
```

```
***Server code****
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
  res.end()
}).listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}. Press Ctrl-C to terminate...`)
})
```

Comment: Your function returns before fs.readFile has finished. Since that method is asynchronous, Node executes it and immediately goes to the bottom of the function and returns you your empty array every time.

Comment: I wouldd say yes.  your console.log is running before the function completes.  you have an async call (readFile), that needs to finish before you try and access the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCircuitAndFuse` must return `Promise` like this:

```js
function getCircuitAndFuse(folderPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //List containing circuit name with its fuse
    let temporaryList = [];

    fs.readFile(__dirname + folderPath, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`Unable to read file: ${error}`);
      } else {
        var $ = cheerio.load(data);

        $('img').each(function (index, element) {
          let getClassAtr = element.attribs.class;
          temporaryList.push(
            getClassAtr.slice(0, getClassAtr.lastIndexOf(' '))
          );
        });

        resolve([...new Set(temporaryList)]);
      }
    });
  });
}

getCircuitAndFuse(folderPath).then((getInfo) => {
  // do something with `getInfo`
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to Faruk's answer would be to just use `fs.readFileSync` instead of wrapping your function in a promise and requiring some of that extra ceremony. Using `fs.readFileSync` will ensure that your function doesn't return prematurely.

Here is your code rewritten with that in mind:

```
function getCircuitAndFuse(folderPath) {
  try {
    let temporaryList = [];
    const data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + folderPath);
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    $("img").each(function (index, element) {
      let getClassAtr = element.attribs.class;
      temporaryList.push(getClassAtr.slice(0, getClassAtr.lastIndexOf(" ")));
    });

    return [...new Set(temporaryList)];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```